# Vue custom search filter doesn't match with v-model value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

This is my code :

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchInput">
<ul>
   <li v-for="(badge, index) in filterBadges" :key="index"></li>
</ul>
```

And my computed function :

```
data() {
  return {
    searchInput: '',
    badges: [
      'JS', 'BitBucket'
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
  filterBadges() {
    return this.badges.filter((badge) => {
      return badge.match(this.searchInput)
    });
  }
}
```

When `searchInput` is empty shows all items in the array but when I type something matching with the array items, It shows empty array.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match method on string accepts only regular expression: see [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

I would do it oldschool way instead:

```
filterBadges() {
    return this.searchInput === '' ? 
        this.badges : 
        this.badges.filter(badge => badge.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInput.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  }
```